# Is the following equation true or false given that three events A,B, and C are in a Sample Space S?

Tags: probability

I have this homework question and I'm not sure how to solve it and prove that it's either true or false? We are given three events A,B and C that are in a sample space S, is the following equation true or false?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Check whether $$1_{A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}}=1_{A\cup B\cup C}-1_{B}-1_{C}+1_{B\cap C}$$

is true. This can be done by discerning $2^3=8$ different cases.

---

**edit**:

The different cases are the $8$ events that can be written as $U\cap V\cap W$ where $U\in\{A,A^c\}$, $V\in\{B,B^c\}$ and $W\in\{C,C^c\}$. These events are disjoint and together they cover the whole space. To give you an idea of this:

- if $\omega\in A\cap B\cap C$ then $1_{A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}}(\omega)=0$ and also $1_{A\cup B\cup C}(\omega)-1_{B}(\omega)-1_{C}(\omega)+1_{B\cap C}(\omega)=1-1-1+1=0$
- $\cdots$
- if $\omega\in A\cap B^c\cap C^c$ then $1_{A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}}(\omega)=1$ and also $1_{A\cup B\cup C}(\omega)-1_{B}(\omega)-1_{C}(\omega)+1_{B\cap C}(\omega)=1-0-0+0=1$
- $\cdots$
- if $\omega\in A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c$ then $1_{A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}}(\omega)=0$ and also $1_{A\cup B\cup C}(\omega)-1_{B}(\omega)-1_{C}(\omega)+1_{B\cap C}(\omega)=0-0-0+0=0$

In all cases (wich means for every $\omega$) the same values appear so the we conclude that the mentioned equality is valid. Then LHS and RHS have equal expectations and this equality is exactly the equality mentioned in your question.

Also checking of the cases can be avoided by observing that $1_{A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}}=1_{A}\left(1-1_{B}\right)\left(1-1_{C}\right)$ and $1_{A\cup B\cup C}-1_{B}-1_{C}+1_{B\cap C}=\left[1_{A}+1_{B}+1_{C}-1_{A}1_{B}-1_{A}1_{C}-1_{B}1_{C}+1_{A}1_{B}1_{C}\right]-1_{B}-1_{C}+1_{B}1_{C}$ both equalize $1_{A}-1_{A}1_{B}-1_{A}1_{C}+1_{A}1_{B}1_{C}$ hence are equal.

Comment: I'm still confused. I see that each piece of the equation you gave me are the corresponding parts from my equation but I still don't know what to do apart from that @drhab?

Comment: I have edited to explain things. If the equality mentioned in the hint is correct then expectation of LHS and RHS must be equal. This results in the equality mentioned in your question.